# How to pass multiple params to hidden attribute?

Tags: angular, html, ionic3

I want to hide a paragraph on two pages. **How do you pass multiple params to hidden attribute?** The **first line is ok** where only one param is needed.

```
<p [hidden]="pageX">Sender Name: {{sender.name}}</p>

I want hide to work on two or more pages, I tried:

<p [hidden]="['pageX, 'pageY']">Sender Name: {{sender.name}}</p>
```

Comment: How exactly are you planning on using this paragraph BTW?

Answer (score 0):

`hidden` property takes `boolean` values. You can do something like

```
<p [hidden]="pageX || pageY">Sender Name: {{sender.name}}</p>
```

But this will still render the `<p></p>` tag. Only  the contents inside will be hidden. A better solution would be to use `ngIf` directive. This will prevent the  `<p></p>` tag from being rendered. Example:

```
<p *ngIf="pageX || pageY">Sender Name: {{sender.name}}</p>
```

Comment: your response was a great lead to the answer:  

    `<p *ngIf="!(pageX || pageY)">Sender Name: {{sender.name}}</p>`

Comment: An up vote would be appreciated if you think my answer helped you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

@Iftifar Taz

Helped me to get the actual solution as ;

```
<p *ngIf="!(pageX || pageY)">Sender Name: {{sender.name}}</p>
```